# iPad/Android support for exotic web technologies

Tags: iphone, android, ipad

We are building a corporate web application that needs to run on every device available out there (on desktops, laptops, iPads, smart phones) etc.

May of the things we need to do in the app (e.g. access local file-system) cannot be done by traditional ways in javascript due to security implications.

Now, we are evaluating various options on how to do accomplish these tasks in a way that needs minimium effort duplication across devices.

The options are are evaluating have mainly narrowed down to Applets/NPAPI plugins for browsers. I know neither Android nor iPad support Applets currently (but Android 2.2 will, is that correct)??

The safest bet I see now is to create a NPAPI plugin for browsers (except IE which would need something based off Active-X).

So, are NPAPI plugins supported by Android/iPad/iPhone browsers as they are for PC based browsers?
Are there any chances Applets would be available for all these platforms in the near future?
Is there a better option available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins and Applets are not and will not be supported in iOS any time soon. Also, there is no file system access on an iPad/iPhone unless it is jailbroken.

Comment: Thanks for replying...
Are you sure "there is no file system access on iPad/iPhone"?? Even for native apps built in objective-c??

Can external apps with custom protocols can be launched in iOS like we can launch them on Desktop (e.g. If you have Skype installed, urls starting with skype:// launch Skype automatically when clicked (I understand these need registry settings on Windos and action handlers on Linux).

Comment: Native apps can only access a few folders relating to themselves. But yes, an app can register a protocol and be launched if it is used in Safari.